# Compare Django model field and request.user.username in HTML

Tags: django, string, if-statement, compare

I want to compare two string. One from the request.user.username, and the other is from the model's attribute (field). When I print them like

```
{{ request.user.profile}}
{{ model.EgysegVezeto }}
```

I see the same two strings, like

```
Chris
Chris
```

but if I use the

```
{% if request.user.profile == model.EgysegVezeto %}
    They are the same!
{% else %}
    They are NOT the same!
{% endif %}
```

it doesn't work, the HTML page says they are two different strings. Why?

The one from the model:

```
EgysegVezeto = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', verbose_name="Egység vezetője")
```

and the other:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.last_name + " " + self.user.first_name)
```

Comment: Have you checked that one doesn't contain a space after it? Like `Chris `. From the example you have gave one contains a space.

Comment: Yes, I printed them like
>{{ request.user.username }}<
>{{ model.attributecontainsname }}<

and I got
>Chris<
>Chris<

Comment: Can you show your model definition for `model.attributecontainsname` and edit your question to show actual attribute name for this model?. If it were a foreign key relationship you could be printing the `__str__` and comparing a model object against a string which would fail the condition yet show same result.

Comment: Edit the question Chris to include Models

Comment: Done it, sorry. I am new in this forum.

Comment: No problem, you have `{{ request.user.profile}}` being printed but using `request.user.username` in the condition, is this correct or a editing mistake?

Comment: Sorry again, editing mistake.

Comment: Final question. Are you comparing First names or usernames?

Comment: A string from first and last name like in the code: str(self.user.last_name + " " + self.user.first_name). I know it is the same string that in the model.EgysegVezeto field, but it says they are not.

Comment: In the meantime, I tested, and the problem is with the request.user.profile. But what could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution for this problem.
For the django default User, I made an extension called Profile, connecting with the User as a OneToOneField:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and it returns the full name of the User, if called:

```
def __str__(self):
    fullname = str(self.user.last_name + " " + self.user.first_name)
    return str(fullname)
```

Now I can use it in the HTML page for an if-statement:

```
{% if request.user.profile == model.Attribute.profile and request.user.profile == model.Attribute.profile %}

{% endif %}
```

The model looks like:

```
class model(models.Model):    
    Attribute = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="User's name", blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that you're comparing the `Profile` model object against a `CharField`(*string*).

The reason why it printed when you called it explicitly in `{{ request.user.profile}}` is because when called to render it will return `__str__` for that model. However when used in a condition it will attempt to compare the model **object** and not the `__str__` method of that model.

**METHOD 1**

Use `.__str__` in condition like so:

```
{% if request.user.profile.__str__ == model.EgysegVezeto %}
```

**METHOD 2**

Convert the object into the string format as used in `__str__`. This can also be done via a template tag:

```py
@register.filter(name='fullname')
def fullname(pk):
    user = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return user.__str__()
```

More information on how to set up template tags are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Then in template use like so:

```
{% if request.user.profile.pk|fullname == model.EgysegVezeto %}
    They are the same!
{% else %}
    They are NOT the same!
{% endif %}
```

The condition will now pass.

Comment: Where should I add the fullname definition?

Comment: I feel **METHOD 1** will be of more convenience to you. However, use the link provided in the answer it should show you how to set up the tags under section *Code Layout*.

Comment: It says for MTEHOD 1:
Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'request.user.profile.__str__'

Anyway, doesn't it return a string when I use this:
return str(self.user.last_name + " " + self.user.first_name)

Comment: Where does it count if the string contains unicode characters like áéőúű?